# Can't import WKT polygon to SNAP

Tags: shapefile, vector, well-known-text, sentinel-snap

I have big size Sentinel-1 image and I would like to clip it to smaller size. For that i'm trying to import shapefile but I get errors all the time:
[image]

This is my polygon WKT:

```
PolygonZ ((102.09338174054019532 16.42902850335272902 0, 102.0873364934548988 16.46965400839237148 0, 102.16886985695849432 16.46841818418501902 0, 102.1701925377519018 16.42887238582805054 0, 102.09338174054019532 16.42902850335272902 0))
```

I really don't understand why wouldn't it work.

[image]

When I show details:

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: PolygonZ (line 1)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.parseErrorWithLine(WKTReader.java:427)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.readGeometryTaggedText(WKTReader.java:495)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.read(WKTReader.java:205)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader.read(WKTReader.java:174)
[catch] at org.esa.snap.rcp.actions.vector.InsertWktGeometryAction.actionPerformed(InsertWktGeometryAction.java:148)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.vsnet.VsnetMenuItemUI.doClick(VsnetMenuItemUI.java:1395)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.vsnet.VsnetMenuItemUI$MouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(VsnetMenuItemUI.java:1190)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you working with shapefile or WKT  ? Also what does it sais when you click show Details ?

Comment: in this case WKT based on a shapefile. And I edited and added

Comment: The first line of the detail : "com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: PolygonZ (line 1) at" point to a geometry not recognized, it could be caused by the polygonZ type if a simple polygon type is expected, try to export to WKT without the Z value (anyway they are all 0)

Comment: I would trust the error message `Unknown geometry type: PolygonZ`. JTS has a long history and 3D geometries were introduced later by OGC. It should still work with x, y, z coordinates if you just edit the geometry type in your WKT into "POLYGON".

Comment: `PolygonZ` is not a valid WKT type designator. Try `POLYGON Z` (with a space). Note that your vertices are at Angstrom precision -- [ob. xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2170/)

Comment: thank you all, it worked when I deleted the Z